# Calculate all time differences between points in R (instead of from one point to the next one)

Tags: r, matrix, time, diff, difference

I would like to calculate the differences in time from POSIXct format. I am able to calculate the differences between consecutive points using

```
diff(data$time)
```

but not from all against all. So I guess my data is at least correctly imported.

I actually want to calculate all distances between points of one individual, so my data looks like: Posix, individual, otherinfo. If there is a simple way i would love to calculate automaticly the differences from all points per indiviual. If its not so straight forward I will do data subsets per individual thats fine.

I would be happy if someone could help me! I tried

```
     dist(data$time)
```

because I know its a distance matrix calculation tool but unfortunalety it just gives me a list of rising numers (1,2,3,...) so i guess it is not familiar with the time format..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply`

```
sapply(data$time, `-`, data$time)
```

---

or with `outer`

```
outer(data$time, data$time, FUN = `-`)
```

Comment: i just tried now: dist(diff(ba004$newtime), method = "euclidean") and it works! i will have to do individual subsets tho. but thats fine. so thank you so much anyway for your fast answer!

i also tried your code now. which unit will it omit do you know?

Comment: which unit will you codes result in?  I have year-month-day Hour:min:sec as data units. when i run your code I get a decimal number

Comment: @Sofia   Probably, better to use `difftime` instead of `-` and specify the `unit` so that there won't be any surprises

Comment: @Sofia Can you try `sapply(data$time, function(x) difftime(data$time, x, unit = "min"))`